# error | 253 | Message specified does not match with any template

Tags: gupshup

I am getting following error while hitting [gupshup](https://www.gupshup.io/developer/home) send message API:

> error | 253 | Message specified does not match with any template

Answer (score 4):

If you are sending any  messages from bulk you need to first approve that template by mailing the message content to enterprise-support@smsgupshup.com with your 10 digit gupshup account Id.  And also note the approved content should exactly match the message which you are trying to send from API even an extra space can cause error 253

Comment: Yes, you are right Seelan. I have uploaded few templetes to gupshup and it is working fine now.

Comment: How to add custom template in smsgupshup API?